# Sprinkle script is giving me this error "Policy myapp is to be installed on :app but no server has such a role."

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sprinkle

I am trying to get [sprinkle](https://github.com/sprinkle-tool/sprinkle) going, but falling at the first hurdle - getting this error:

"Policy myapp is to be installed on :app but no server has such a role."

This is my script:

```
package :ubuntu_version do
  runner "lsb_release -r"
end


policy :myapp, :roles => :app do
  requires :ubuntu_version
end

deployment do
  delivery :ssh do
    user 'root'
    password 'secret'
    role :app, 'server'
  end
end
```

Here is the full error:

```
$ sprinkle -c -s install_kimptoc2.rb                             
/Users/kimptoc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@p-box-mgr/gems/sprinkle-0.5.2/lib/sprinkle/policy.rb:87:in `process': Policy myapp is to be installed on :app but no server has such a role. (Sprinkle::Policy::NoMatchingServersError)
  from /Users/kimptoc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@p-box-mgr/gems/sprinkle-0.5.2/lib/sprinkle/deployment.rb:79:in `block in process'
    from /Users/kimptoc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@p-box-mgr/gems/sprinkle-0.5.2/lib/sprinkle/deployment.rb:78:in `each'
    from /Users/kimptoc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@p-box-mgr/gems/sprinkle-0.5.2/lib/sprinkle/deployment.rb:78:in `process'
    from /Users/kimptoc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@p-box-mgr/gems/sprinkle-0.5.2/lib/sprinkle/script.rb:20:in `sprinkle'
    from /Users/kimptoc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@p-box-mgr/gems/sprinkle-0.5.2/lib/sprinkle/script.rb:16:in `sprinkle'
    from /Users/kimptoc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@p-box-mgr/gems/sprinkle-0.5.2/bin/sprinkle:108:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/kimptoc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@p-box-mgr/bin/sprinkle:19:in `load'
    from /Users/kimptoc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@p-box-mgr/bin/sprinkle:19:in `<main>'
    from /Users/kimptoc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@p-box-mgr/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /Users/kimptoc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@p-box-mgr/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

I started from this [Miso](http://engineering.gomiso.com/2011/08/26/forget-chef-or-puppet-automate-with-sprinkle/) guide. Also checked out the [cheatsheet](http://maxim.github.io/sprinkle-cheatsheet/) and [passenger-stack](https://github.com/benschwarz/passenger-stack).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this is a bug with this version of Sprinkle (0.5.2)

https://github.com/sprinkle-tool/sprinkle/issues/109

Answer (score 2):

I had this error after upgrading sprinkle and checking my `install.rb` configuration file:

`sprinkle -s install.rb -t`

I am using capistrano, and I do have a "app" role in my capistrano deploy.rb file. I also have a `packages/deploy.rb` package that creates a deploy user, adds SSH keys etc.

For myself I fixed the error by making sure `requires :deploy` was specified in the policy configuration:

```
policy :appserver, :roles => :app do
  requires :deploy
end
```

And that delivery and capistrano were configured as follows in the deployment block, based on the [example configuration from the Sprinkle documentation](https://github.com/sprinkle-tool/sprinkle/blob/master/README.md#appendix).

```
deployment do
  delivery :capistrano do
    recipes 'deploy'
  end
end
```

With those changes, when I re-check the configuration, I no longer see that exception raised.